# What is the best pattern to sync data between two recycler view with two activities?

Tags: android, design-patterns, synchronization, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have two activities where they have almost same data, I am using same Adapter, But the problem is how to sync data.

E.g. 
**Activity A** has *recyclerview* where it has like buttons in each row with unique id. **Activity B** also have *same recyclerview* but with some **filter mechanism** so it is not going to show all row, my question is how to handle like button state in **Activity A** and **Activity B**, such that if I click on **activity B's like** button than **activity A's like button** will automatically gets checked and vice versa.

Comment: Maintain a flag kind of thing in ur adapter's pojo class make it static so that when Activity A's like button is clicked it will automatically show up in Activity B's like button at the time of rendering in getView method

Comment: It depends in which way you want, either server side or locally. Check answer given by readyandroid may be it will helpfull for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use common data source for both the recycler views.

1. Get data from API
2. Save data in your local db
3. Feed the data to your Activity A recycler view
4. Feed the same data to your Activity B recycler view
5. All the changes you make to data should be in local db so both the
   views can update automatically.

Comment: Dont u think use of database should be avoided till the time it can be?

Comment: Well it actually depends on the use case .Most google apps rely heavily on content providers for their functioning.I don't think making a single table would make much difference.

Comment: So,If i want to get new data every time when app gets started than i need to flush sqlite data? and each time when i go to Activity A or Activity B than i need to notify adapter?

Comment: Yes, you have to maintain same state locally and on your server.Every time new data comes overwrite the previous one.

Comment: Rahul's answer makes sense. In your case, you need to update the record which is liked from the recycler view and fetch the records afresh when displaying it in the other activity. This is necessary as there needs to be some way of storing the liked/not liked status iof each of these items. This is where SQLite helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use static modifier

1. define BaseRecyclerView which has a static list of the items
2. extend CustomRecyclerView's from BaseRecyclerView
3. when you manipulate the items in list such as setting like flag the list in two CustomRecyclerView's will be changed because of static modifier

Answer (score 0):

**Manage Locally:**

Your same list of data should be accessible in both of the activities. You can save that list in your application class. And if you don't want to save in Application class then on every switch of Activity you have to pass that list data between both activities.

Next thing in Model class you have to make one more variable to save a state for like button, once you make it like then I should save that value and when you went to retrieve that same list data it will give you updated data for like button event.

Through code you can achieve:

```
class MyApplication extends Application{
public static ArrayList<MyModel> myModelList = new ArrayList<>();
}

class MyModel{
public boolean isLikeSelected;
}
```

**Activity A:**

```
onLikeClick(int position){
MyApplication.myModelList.get(position).isLikeSelected = !MyApplication.myModelList.get(position).isLikeSelected;
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

**Activity B:**

```
onLikeClick(int position){
MyApplication.myModelList.get(position).isLikeSelected = !MyApplication.myModelList.get(position).isLikeSelected;
adapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
}
```

Here your application class is having static ArrayList which can be accessible throughout the app and have a stable and updated record of list data.

**Using Server:**

On every click at like button you will update to the server for the event and next time on Activity switch you will get updated list from the server, so no need to worry in case of server management.

Comment: Hi, your logic makes sense when i have same data in both activities but not for filtered data, there may chance i have some different rows too, so i guess Rahul's answer makes sense for this, btw thanks for reply :)