# How to update the UI in android

Tags: android, listview

I have an activity A with a listview and upon selecting some items in the list, and navigating to another activity B with the selected items in the list of Activity A. And made some modifications. After return to A. My screen is not updating with the latest modifications.

Please guide me how to do this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: And how are we suppose to know what these modifications you're speaking of? You need to write your code here, explain and tell us the line that you think is supposed to do something but its not doing what you need.

Comment: put your UI update code in **onResume()** of your A activity

Comment: Refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/40815714/3237960

Answer (score 1):

If you have unified data storage for both activities (so that you know that this problem is purely UI issue, because the data itself is updated upon returning from activity B), then you should call this method on your ListView adapter:

```
yourListView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to display what you want, you need to have some `TextView`s in your other activity and then just add a text to them to display what you need.

When you get the data, just do like this in the `onCreate` method:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)inflate.findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
tv.setText(theDataStringYouReceived);
```